# Shader issue in SpriteKit

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, sprite-kit, shader, tvos

I'm trying to add a shader to a stroke I've drawn in SpriteKit using SKShapeNode's stokeShader property but I can't get any effect on the stroke color in any way. I have a custom path I have drawn and created a SKShapeNode along that path. I'm trying to get some custom coloring along the path's stroke but I can't get this shader to work.

```
SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
shape.path = path.CGPath;
shape.lineWidth = 20.0;
shape.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


SKShader *shader = [SKShader shaderWithFileNamed:@"neonLineShader.fsh"];
NSLog(@"Shader = %@",shader);
shape.strokeShader = shader;
```

I'm using super simple shader code just for testing but can't get any change in the stroke color.

```
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

I've tried adding a texture to the stroke first but no luck there.